# managing GeoIP data files

Tags: updates

On a Ubuntu 20.04 desktop I am seeing a number of unrecognized IP addresses on an app to log countries that visit the site.  I looked at /usr/share/GeoIP and find the databases are dated Jan 23 2020.  I used geoipupdate to download new data but I find the data formats are not the same.  My geoip.conf is correct.  How do I get the MaxMind data to .dat format?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`geolite2legacy`](https://github.com/sherpya/geolite2legacy) to convert the new format to the old `.dat`-format.
... or Download ready files from https://mailfud.org/geoip-legacy/